# How to make ext.net RadioGroup a required field?

Tags: ext.net

We are using `ext.net`. I know how to make a textbox a required field, but am having trouble to force our user to make a selection on the radio group or a check box group. I know someone just assign a default value to one of the radio button, but our customer wants to leave them unchecked in the beginning but forces the web users to make a choice, which is understandable.

It appears `IndicatorText` and `AllowBlank` properties are not effective even though they are listed in the IntelliSense.

```
<ext:RadioGroup ID="rdGrpGender" runat="server" 
      ItemCls="x-check-group-base" FieldLabel="Gender"
      ColumnsWidths="60,60" 
      IndicatorText="*" IndicatorCls="cssIndicator" AllowBlank="false">
      <Items>
          <ext:Radio ID="rdoMale" runat="server" BoxLabel="M" />
          <ext:Radio ID="rdoFemale" runat="server" BoxLabel="F" />
      </Items>
</ext:RadioGroup>
```

Can any expert help me out? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can validate it like this

```
    <ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Validate"><Listeners><Click Handler="#{rdGrpGender}.validate();" /></Listeners></ext:Button>
```